# What do I use to repair holes in homasote attached to exterior brick wall?

Tags: repair, walls

My Harrisburg PA brick ranch house was built in 1960.
We are remodeling the kitchen and have removed the drywall and insulation on the exterior wall.

The brick exterior is faced with homasote and has holes that need repaired.
I think the holes were created when a fire broke out the kitchen in the 80’s (we did not live here then), and firemen were using tools to quickly remove cabinets and wallboard to look for smoldering fires. The holes vary in size from 1 inch to 5 inches, and because it is homasote some of the holes are a bit ragged.

What material would you recommend to repair the holes in the homasote, which is the original material they used to face our homes brick exterior?
Would Dash Patch be appropriate for this application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Homasote® is still available.

Buy a sheet and cut patches (with nice straight edges) bigger than each hole. Lay a patch over a hole and cut out a new hole to just fit the patch. Remove the extra old Homasote® around the existing old hole and install the new patch.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a similar material(pressed fibre board) and cut the holes square and patch.  Some duct tape should hold the patches in.  A local builder might have some left over part sheets.

Buying enough sheets to cut to fit between the studs where the holes are and just doubling over will work also, without patching.  An extra 1/2 inch should not reduce the insulating factor of the insulation from compression.

If you do not mind losing an extra 2 inches from the floor area, this would be a good time to add 2x2s to the studs to increase the insulation R factor.  I imagine a 60s house to have 2x4 studs on the outside walls, more modern houses use 2x6s for greater insulation value.